# Getting the name of a button while the progress bar is going on in webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have one button named "Add" in my web portal. On clicking on that button a progress bar appears and the name of the button gets changed to "Adding" from "Add" and remains "Adding" until the progress bar is not moved to 100%. After the progress bar is 100% complete, again the text of Add button changes back to "Add" from "Adding".

I need to assert whether the name of the button is changing from "Add" to "Adding" or not during the progress bar movement. But the problem is once I click on the "Add" button, then use the assertion, selenium will first click on "Add" button, completes the progress bar to 100% and then tries to assertion, but now already the text of "Add" button is already changed back to "Add" from "Adding".

Please give the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the element, click and **immediately** return it's text which can be used later for `Assert`

```
public string Test()
{    
    IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Something"));
    element.Click();
    return element.Text;
}

Assert.IsTrue(Test().Contains("Adding"));
```

Note: C# code